# Why does checksec.sh highlight rpath and runpath as security issues?

Tags: hardening

The tool [checksec.sh](https://github.com/slimm609/checksec.sh) is used to examine compile time hardening options such as NX, RELRO, PIE and so on.[image]

It also reports if the binary has RPATH or RUNPATH set, using the following logic:
[image]

These are flagged as red when present.

What is the security risk of having RPATH or RUNPATH set?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

TL;DR: `R*PATH` has an unfortunate history of introducing new ways of
running untrusted (attacker-controlled) libraries. `RPATH`/`RUNPATH`
is usually avoidable and should be avoided.

Firstly, it might be worth reviewing the non-security reasons for why
we want these binaries flagged: distros (Eg. [Debian Wiki on
RPATH](https://wiki.debian.org/RpathIssue)) don't like that it [takes precedence](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ld.so) over the local
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `/etc/ld.so.conf` settings/configs and
conventions. It makes it harder to reason about libraries through more
visible means than running `readelf` for every binary we want to think
about, and it complicates life for maintainers who are juggling a lot
of intertwined dependencies through these other mechanisms which are
easily broken by `RPATH`/`RUNPATH`. But there are exceptions - here's
Debian's policy:

> The only time a binary or shared library in a Debian package should set `RPATH` or `RUNPATH` is if it is linked to private shared libraries in the same package.

Secondly, relative `RPATH` (i.e. `foo.so` rather than
`/usr/lib/foo.so`) can go quite wrong: your user might be running from
a working directory (Eg. `/tmp`) that's subject to attacker control
who could plant a malicious version of `/tmp/foo.so`. This was an
observation made in [Debian bug #754278 against openjdk](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=754278).

This might sound benign, but it can lead to privesc particularly on
setuid/setgid programs like [IBM's DB2 privesc CVE-2014-0907](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21672100):
simply run the suid binary from a directory primed to abuse whatever
`RPATH` is set, and your code will run in the context of the
privileged program. Other examples include [Slackware's packaging of
llvm CVE-2013-7171](http://www.slackware.com/security/viewer.php?l=slackware-security&y=2013&m=slackware-security.395467), [Gentoo's packaging of Imagemagick
CVE-2005-3582](https://security.gentoo.org/glsa/200511-02), [SuSE's packaging of CVSup CVE-2004-2133](http://marc.info/?l=bugtraq&m=107539776002450&w=2), ..).
It's been such a steady trickle that [Apple's equivalent avoids relative RPATH](https://github.com/opensource-apple/dyld/blob/3f928f32597888c5eac6003b9199d972d49857b5/src/dyld.cpp#L2885) in "restricted" (suid/sgid) binaries.

Thirdly, the special `$ORIGIN` variable (calling executable path) has
been one way of avoiding an absolute path, while anchoring the search
*somewhere*. But it's had issues: [glibc CVE-2011-0536](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=667974) failed to
expand it properly which gave attackers an equivalent of the relative RPATH case where the author of an executable using `$ORIGIN` thought they were getting something slightly more robust.

With that in mind, you probably really do want `checksec.sh` to flag
`RPATH`/`RUNPATH` - it's not always bad, but `checksec.sh` doesn't
have the bigger picture available to make that call for you like the
distro linters can, so it needs manual review.

Addendum: [Breaking the links: Exploiting the linker](https://www.nth-dimension.org.uk/pub/BTL.pdf) by Tim Brown was mentioned in the replies to your Twitter conversation, this is a great paper on attack surface more generally for POSIX style linkers and astute readers should definitely take a look. The most pertinent thing there not covered already is this:

> On GNU/Linux at least, when the `DT_RPATH` or `DT_RUNPATH` exists within the ELF headers of a binary then these will be honoured first when looking for shared libraries. Additionally, the keyword `$ORIGIN` within this header is expanded to be the path of the directory where the object
>   is found, while both . and the empty directory specification are honoured, even for binaries with the setUID bit set. From an attackers pespective, setUID binaries with `DT_RPATH` are particularly nice, since we can make use of hard links to manipulate the runtime linker into using an `$ORIGIN`
>   which we can control.

... as observed elsewhere in the paper, most systems ignore user-supplied environment variables such as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on setuid binaries most of the time, but as you can see a careless `RPATH` gives the attacker an equivalent gift.

2nd addendum: ContextIS have a [great writeup covering RPATH attacks](https://www.contextis.com/blog/linux-privilege-escalation-via-dynamically-linked-shared-object-library).

Comment: Thanks, awesome answer, especially with all of the references.